# How does Google Flights define classes?

Tags: flight-search-engines, luxury

Why is Norwegian's "Premium Cabin" shown when I search for Premium Economy while Icelandair's "Saga Class" shown when I search for Business? The amenities are similar across both classes but Norwegian's has a larger seat pitch so I'd expect it to be the one listed in a better class not vice versa.

Similarly Azores Airlines' "Executive" class has similar amenities and smaller seats than LEVEL's "Premium Economy" but Azores' "Executive" is listed as business on Flights.

What criteria do Google Flights use to classify different products across airlines?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fare_basis_code - there’s a standard for core booking codes that an airline can use, but there’s no standard for what the product being sold under that booking code has to be.  An airline could trivially sell an economy basic fare under a booking code for Business (J) and aggregators like Google Flights would treat it like any other business class product - because it is, just a bad one.

Comment: @Moo There has to be some mapping, because different airlines use different fare class structures. LEVEL's premium economy is sold as T class, based on an ITA Matrix search I just did, while T class is a deep-discount economy ticket on United. So somewhere within the GDS or Google Flights or some system, there's presumably a table that maps "T class on LEVEL" to "premium economy."

Comment: @ZachLipton nothing official anywhere - if an aggregator wishes to map the fare to their own internal system then they either make the determination themselves or they ask the source for a mapping.  Each aggregator will be doing this.

Comment: @ZachLipton: Exactly — Google flights is clearly making some mapping from airlines’ internal fare classes to a standard set, and this question is asking roughly how that mapping is defined.

Comment: @PLL and the answer to that question is “they make it up or they ask the airline”.  There’s no magic involved.

Comment: @Moo: Obviously there’s no magic involved, but there is almost certainly some system.  If they “make it up”, they probably do so by checking what each airline class offers against some standard list of criteria.  If they “ask the airline”, they must also still check that the airline’s answer is reasonable; perhaps also the airlines’ individual mappings are published somewhere.  If the mapping really is totally arbitrary and can’t be further explained, as you seem to suggest, then that itself would be an interesting answer, if you have any sources or reasoning to back it up.

Comment: @PLL that’s just it, there aren’t any decent sources or reasoning to back any of this up - once upon a time, the IATA set the fare codes airlines could use but that is a distant memory and airlines these days can literally make new codes up on a whim for a new product or change an existing product to something completely different without changing the fare code.  The whole thing around airline fares means that often airlines don’t know how much a fare exactly is until it’s sold (there are several questions on this, it’s hilariously complex).

Comment: @PLL add to that the fact that an airlines product can change based on origin airport or even aircraft operating a route on that day, and it makes for a complex setup - J on one day or one route may not be the same as J on another.

Comment: @Moo There is an industry standard way to disseminate the fare-code–cabin map, allowing the flexibility you desire. The fall back default position that, *e.g.*, `J` = business is also well defined by an IATA Resolution. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What criteria do Google Flights use to classify different products across airlines?

The airlines themselves provide the definition. It is not up to the travel agents (online or otherwise) to redefine the cabin classes. I imagine such re-interpretations would be a violation of a TA's agency agreement with the airline: the travel agent is an agent for the airline, contractually obliged to operate in accordance with the airline's wishes. It is not a free shop that can market goods bought in bulk however it sees fit.

---

Network airlines file their fares (and much more information) centrally either with **ATPCO**, the Airline Tariff Publishing Company, or with **SITA**, le Société Internationale de Télécommunications Aéronautiques. Some of the larger airlines file with both, but ATPCO is by far the dominant publisher. (To my knowledge, there are no other competitors, and each is actually owned by a conglomerate of airlines, as industry bodies, not freely trading companies.)

Among fare tariffs, service fees, frequent flyer status maps and other information, the airlines may also use this service to define how their fare classes map to cabins.

These two companies then publish their data on to the Global Distribution Systems such as Amadeus or Sabre (and other interested parties, for a substantial fee). A GDS combines all these delayed data with live availability information and a direct reservation feed to each airline, allowing travel agents to price itineraries, reserve space, and issue tickets.

I will now ignore SITA since I have little experience with them.

ATPCO provides a **Reservation Booking Designator by Cabin Answer Table**. It describes the table in the documentation thus.

> The RBD Answer table product provides subscribers with a listing of carriers’ RBDs and their associated cabin (Premium First, First, Premium Business, Business, Premium Economy, and Economy).  A carrier’s RBD Answer Table may consist of several sequences with a listing of RBDs and their associated cabin that apply only if specific global indicator, geographic locale, travel/ticketing dates flight numbers and equipment are matched.

Like most of ATPCO's feeds, it's a simple fixed-width text file, in a format last updated in the early 90s, compressed with gzip and pushed once per day over FTP to each customer, either complete, or in differential form (only the differences since yesterday) if the customer prefers.

It's a flexible format in some respects, allowing a particular fare booking code (or "reservation booking designator") such as `Y` to define one of several pre-specified cabins. That mapping can be restricted by airline (obviously), tariff (such as "AT" for transatlantic), equipment (such as "744" for a 747-400), specific flight number, city pair, country pair, travel date, and a few other conditions, but most airlines don't refine on these parameters beyond the booking code.

On the other hand, it's inflexible in that the only allowed cabin designators are

- Premium First
- First
- Premium Business
- Business
- Premium Economy
- Economy

As an example of this limitation, BA used to have `R` class for supersonic class, but that sadly is no longer the case. I believe it was branded as business in the GDS.

---

However, airlines can now arrange for a further distinction using "Branded fares". This allows arbitrary names to be given to cabins. For instance, BA brands its business services as "Club Europe" (shorthaul intra-Europe), "Club World" (intercontinentally) and "Club" (shorthaul within Southern Africa). This is not universally supported.

---

If the airline declines to provide this information, then ATPCO instructs that you should use the default definitions specified in IATA Resolution 728. This says that `P`, `F`, and `A` is first class; `J`, `C`, `D`, `I`, and `Z` is business; `W` is premium economy; and `S`, `Y`, `H`, `B`, `K`, `L`, `M`, `N`, `Q`, `T`, `V`, and `X` are economy. (It's actually refined a bit further because historically IATA's "any airline" YY fares were priced for different buckets, but the commercial need for that has probably gone now.) `E`, `G`, `O`, `R`, and `U` are left unspecified, but ATPCO documentation states they should be treated as economy if the marketing carrier did not provide an alternative description.

Sometimes we see mistakes like Aer Lingus `F` fares being described as first class. Examination of the RBD answer table shows that this should be considered economy.